# Representing hierarchical data with jstree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jstree

I am having trouble representing hierarchical data in Ruby on Rails, using jsTree to visualize the data in a "tree folder structure".  To test the plugin with sample data, I followed this tutorial:  http://beginrails.blogspot.ca/2012/03/jstree-introduction.html

The application I am writing is a very basic "skills inventory", with a Page (the type of skill) and User (a person with a skill) model.  The pages are hierarchical, meaning one page can be the "parent" of multiple pages, which can be parents for multiple other pages, and so on.  At the point of when a "page" does not have any more children, that page will contain "users".  Using the sample data, the application should produce results such as this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnihP.png

Each page has a `parent_id` field, and all pages are standalone (meaning that they are all contained within `Page.all`).  If the `parent_id` field is `nil`, then the page will only contains users.  Each page also has a `links` array where the IDs of the child pages are stored.  These two fields are the basis of the hierarchical structure of the data.  My question is: how would I be able to loop through all of the pages and set up the correct HTML for jsTree to properly visualize the data?

The Pages model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: pages
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  parent_id  :integer
#  name       :string(255)
#  links      :text
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActsAsTree
  acts_as_tree order: "name"
  attr_accessible :links, :name, :parent_id
  serialize :links
  WillPaginate.per_page = 10
end
```

The relevant part of my Pages controller:

```
def index
  @pages = Page.all

  # any additional change could go here

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @pages }
  end
end
```

The "index" view of the application (which is where the jsTree visualization would go:

```
<div id="treeview">
    <ul>
        <!-- jsTree logic and looping through data goes here -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am a beginner Rails programmer, so any constructive criticism would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you ask for constructive critisism, so:

Your tree definition is in a pretty unusal way. Normaly parent_id points to the parent, so pages without a parent_id are root elements and pages without children (meaning without other pages having this page as parent) are leaves.

That's also the way acts_as_tree works.

Next, you have to build the tree as a JSON object. That means, you need to construct the nodes recursively. Each node consists of the name and the children.

The children are either the child pages or the associated users.

This tree construction is best done in the page model:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActsAsTree
  attr_accessible :name, :parent_id

  acts_as_tree order: 'name'
  has_many :users

  def node
    {data: name, children: leaves}
  end

  def leaves
    if children.any?
      children.map{|child| child.node}
    else
      users.map{|user| {data: user.name}}
    end
  end
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :page_id
  belongs_to :page
end
```

To construct your test tree I created some pages and users:

```
p1=Page.create name:'Laundry'
p2==Page.create name:'Java Programming'
p3==p2.children.create name:'Game Development'
p4==p2.children.create name:'Console Applications'

p1.users.create name: 'Bob Smith'
p1.users.create name: 'Chuck Norris'
p3.users.create name:'Nuck Chorris'
p4.users.create name:'Sob Bmith'
```

Now to construct your JSON-tree, you need all root pages and their trees:

```
Page.roots.map{|r| r.node}
=> [{:data=>"Java Programming", :children=>[{:data=>"Console Applications", :children=>[{:data=>"Sob Bmith"}]}, {:data=>"Game Development", :children=>[{:data=>"Nuck Chorris"}]}]}, {:data=>"Laundry", :children=>[{:data=>"Bob Smith"}, {:data=>"Chuck Norris"}]}]
```

So your controller looks like:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: Page.roots.map{|r| r.node}}
    end
  end
end
```

I leave it to you, to let jsTree collect the JSON-tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This seems like an extremely efficient way of doing it!

Comment: Another question:  using this structure, how would I be able to add the same user to multiple pages?

Comment: Then you need a `has_and_belongs_to_may` relationship between page and user. This is using a joining table `pages_users`. See [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I have set this relationship up between the two models, and I have created the joining table, but how do I actually associate a user object that has already been created to multiple page objects?  If this is not possible, how do I instantiate a user object that already has its page associations in place?

Comment: that's a bit too long to answer in a comment. Could you ask it in a new question?